# How do I do functions.from_csv at spark structured stream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I read lines from a kafka source and I want to build a kafka consumer... in spark structured streaming
I know how to tell spark that the incoming lines are json type... how do I do the same with from_csv ?

```
   val lines = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "topic2")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .load()
      .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .select(functions.from_json($"value", retailDataSchema).as("data"))
      lines.printSchema()
```

The schema is:

```
        val retailDataSchema = new StructType()
          .add("InvoiceNo", IntegerType)
          .add("Quantity", IntegerType)
          .add("Country", StringType)
```

Thank you!

The input data looks like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this work around:

```
    val lines = spark
            .readStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
            .option("subscribe", "topic2")
            .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
            .load()
            .select(col("value").cast("string")).as("data").select("data.*").selectExpr("cast(split(value,',')[0] as DataTypes.IntegerType) as InvoiceNo"
                    ,"cast(split(value,',')[1] as DataTypes.IntegerType) as Quantity"
                    ,"cast(split(value,',')[2] as DataTypes.StringType) as Country" );
    lines.printSchema();
```

> Or you could use the built-in function `from_csv` Since Apache spark 3.0.0

```
val lines = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "topic2")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .select(functions.from_csv($"value", retailDataSchema).as("data"))
  lines.printSchema()
```

[Apache Spark Docs for `from_csv` built-in function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_csv)

Comment: First of all, in the two .readStream you have to remove the parenthesis (). Secondly by adding your code there is an exception for mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'ADD', 'AFTER', 'ALL'}after retailDataSchema. The purpose of my code is to tell kafka that the imput lines are comma separated values. Lastly, I do not understand the reason for the .csv("path").

Comment: @vasilis If my answer solve your problem, please accept it as the right answer